# How to organize Rails app where each customer has it's own specific gem list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, rubygems

I'm creating an architecture of the app and trying to find the best one. Few words about it:

- Box solution (each app installed on customer's machine)
- There is a Main app and gems to extend it (private)
- Main app has default list of gem
- Other functionality extending by adding additional gems by request (our gems)

But some customers no need full functionality, so we don't need to include all gems to it's Gemfile.

**What is the best way to organize it?** What do you think about this way? Maybe you can offer more effective way?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider making your "main app" or core functionality [a mountable engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) and not a Rails application.

That means packing the controllers, models, and routes into a gem that is added to a stock Rails application which is customized to the specific customer. This is how CMS:es like Refinery and Radiant are structured.

This allows full freedom for each "Box" to have whatever settings and gems it wants. This is especially important if you intend to let clients self host (which is a nightmare).

It also makes developing and updating the core easier as bundler will resolve the gem dependencies. You would add the "default" gems as dependencies of your mountable engine gem.

If you want to make creating/updating/developing the individual apps easier you could set this up as GIT forks of a "template" application.

Comment: But I can't packing all controllers, models and routes in one gem. There are ~5 layers which customer should chose. How to resolve it?